# AWS instance not connecting after running `chmod` command

Tags: aws, putty

I ran a `chmod 777` command on my instance and after that I closed my terminal.

Since then I haven't been able to connect putty or WinScp.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

There's not a lot you can do.

You have broken the install entirely, your only real option at this point is to rebuild the AWS instance OR restore a snapshot (I hope you were taking snapshots!).